# SQL Remove Blank Data

Tags: sql, null

So here is the story,

```
SELECT STOCK_TABLE.Product_Name,STOCK_TABLE.Product_Stock
From STOCK_TABLE
```

inside Product_Name contain:

- shirt
- jeans
- cap
- T-Shirt

and it also have a Stock Number inside     STOCK_TABLE.Product_Stock

When The stock of, for example Shirt is empty, above query will show the Product name but the product stock is empty because its empty. 
The situation that i want is if the product stock is empty, the product name will also disappear. 
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT STOCK_TABLE.Product_Name,STOCK_TABLE.Product_Stock
From STOCK_TABLE
WHERE STOCK_TABLE.Product_Stock>0 and STOCK_TABLE.Product_Stock is not null
```

However, this is basic SQL, you might want to read up on the language.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I get your question right, but shouldn't the following work?

```
SELECT STOCK_TABLE.Product_Name,STOCK_TABLE.Product_Stock
  FROM STOCK_TABLE 
 WHERE STOCK_TABLE.Product_Stock != 'empty'
```

Or if STOCK_TABLE.Product_Stock a number of pieces

```
SELECT STOCK_TABLE.Product_Name,STOCK_TABLE.Product_Stock
  FROM STOCK_TABLE 
 WHERE STOCK_TABLE.Product_Stock > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query you're probably looking for (T-SQL version):

```
SELECT S.Product_Name
     ,S.Product_Stock
FROM STOCK_TABLE S
WHERE S.Product_Stock IS NOT NULL
    AND S.Product_Stock > 0
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding where filter

```
SELECT STOCK_TABLE.Product_Name,STOCK_TABLE.Product_Stock
From STOCK_TABLE 
Where STOCK_TABLE.Product_Stock OR STOCK_TABLE.Product_Stock IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query:

```
SELECT STOCK_TABLE.Product_Name,STOCK_TABLE.Product_Stock
From STOCK_TABLE 
WHERE STOCK_TABLE.Product_Stock IS NOT NULL
```